# jQuery Validation for related from fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to validate a form that has the below structure:

```
<form id="myform" action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form 1</legend>
        <label for="field1">Certificate Number</label>
        <input id="field1" type="text" class="myClass1" name="field1" placeholder="field1">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Form 2</legend>
        <label for="field2">Certificate Number</label>
        <input id="field2" type="text" class="myClass2" name="field2" placeholder="field2">
        <br>
        <label for="field3">Redemption Code</label>
        <input id="field3" type="text" class="myClass2" name="field3" placeholder="field3">
    </fieldset>
    <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

I want to validate the below condition:

```
(field1 || (field2 && field3))
```

this is quite straightforward, but I am not sure how to implement this with the jQuery Validate plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a way to use [`require_from_group`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/).

Though you can use `required` as a function like below:-

```js
$('#myform').validate({
  rules: {
    field1:{
        required:function (){ return !$('#field2').val().length && !$('#field3').val().length; }
      },
    field2:{
        required:function (){ return !$('#field1').val().length }
      },
    field3:{
        required:function (){ return !$('#field1').val().length }
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

<form id="myform" action="#" method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 1</legend>
    <label for="field1">Certificate Number</label>
    <input id="field1" type="text" class="myClass1" name="field1" placeholder="field1">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Form 2</legend>
    <label for="field2">Certificate Number</label>
    <input id="field2" type="text" class="myClass2" name="field2" placeholder="field2">
    <br>
    <label for="field3">Redemption Code</label>
    <input id="field3" type="text" class="myClass2" name="field3" placeholder="field3">
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Continue">
</form>
```

Comment: Or you can use the custom `:blank` selector.  `return $('#field1').is(':blank')`.  See:  https://jqueryvalidation.org/category/selectors/#:blank-selector